# Python script to convert xml to csv

Tags: python, xml, csv

i have an XML file as below shortened of course there are repeated tags foe  and :

```
<file version=3.6 xmlns:xsi="http://ww.w3.org/2009/XMLSchemainstance">
  <Date>2014-05-12</Date>
 <creationTime>2014-05-12 :56:54</creationTime>
<location>http://www.w.org/2009/XMLSchemainstance/output/official/.20140512.PNL.xml.gz</location>
<contentType>nnn</contentType>
<signOffBy>gft_test_fo</signOffBy>
<signOffGroup>BRFPOOLNEW_SO</signOffGroup>
<book>
    <riskBook>BRFPOOL</riskBook>
    <trade>
        <tradeId>00000000000009752</tradeId>
     <subTrade>
        <riskTrade>00000000000009752</riskTrade>
        <riskProductType>BOND_NF</riskProductType>
       <reportCollection>
      <report>
         <valuationSource>RISK_ENGINE</valuationSource>
         <reportName>BRZ_HGS_PPTCC</reportName>
         <riskPoint>
           <value>0.00</value>
           <valueCcy>BRL</valueCcy>
          </riskPoint>
       </report> 
        <report>
         <valuationSource>RISK_ENGINE</valuationSource>
         <reportName>BRZ_HGS_PPTCC</reportName>
         <riskPoint>
           <value>0.00</value>
           <valueCcy>BRL</valueCcy>
          </riskPoint>
        </report>         
      </reportCollection>
      </subTrade>
     </trade>
   </book>
</file>
```

I want the output as csv as follows:

```
Date,creationTime,location,contentType,signOffBy,signOffGroup,riskBook,tradeId,riskTrade,riskProductType,reportName,valuationSource,reportName,value,valueCcy
2014-05-12,2014-05-12 :56:54,http://ww.w3.org/2009/XMLSchemainstance/output/official/GLOBAL/GLOBAL_EM/BRFPOOL.20140512.PNL.xml.gz,nnn,gft_test_fo,BRFPOOLNEW_SO,BRFPOOL,00000000000009752,00000000000009752,BOND_NF,RISK_ENGINE,BRZ_HGS_PPTCC,0.00,BRL
2014-05-12,2014-05-12 :56:54,http://ww.w3.org/2009/XMLSchemainstance/output/official/GLOBAL/GLOBAL_EM/BRFPOOL.20140512.PNL.xml.gz,PNL,gft_test_fo,BRFPOOLNEW_SO,BRFPOOL,00000000000009752,00000000000009752,BOND_NF,RISK_ENGINE,BRZ_HGS_PPTCC,0.00,BRL
```

here is the code i have tried so far:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
root=etree.parse('./emp.xml').getroot()
for b in zip(root.findall("book/trade/tradeId"),root.findall  ("book/trade/subTrade/riskTrade"),root.findall("book/trade/subTrade/riskProductType"),root.findall("book/trade/subTrade/reportcollectin/report/valuationSource"),("book/trade/subTrade/reportcollectin/report/reportName"),("book/trade/subTrade/reportcollectin/report/refCurve"),("book/trade/subTrade/reportcollectin/report/riskPoint/value"),("book/trade/subTrade/reportcollectin/report/riskPoint/valueCcy")
    print (",".join([x.text for x in b]))
```

I am not getting the output I expected, Please help me on this.

Comment: What happens with the above code? Do you see an error?

Comment: @shaktimaan i am not getting output as expected

Comment: Please fix your indentation and mark it as code

Comment: there is no problem in indentaion i am getting output but wrong

Comment: I referred to your code in the question - not the indentation of your actual python code :)

Comment: The example is missing an ending quote in the statement `root=etree.parse('./emp.xml).getroot()` (need `'` after `'./emp.xml`).

Answer (score 2):

Besides the errors in the XML (there's no end tag on `<creationTime>` and on `<file>`) and in the python file (there's no end quote in the file name and some path routes are misspelled like `reportcollectin`) you cannot use the `zip` function when are two different size list involved, the result is always the lower length and in the code you are searching for `root.findall("book/trade/subTrade/reportCollection/report/refCurve")` which is a empty list and the final result end in a empty list too.

The best approach is get the principal variables first (Date, creationTime, creationTime) and then iterate over books and reports using loops.

Comment: Please provide me an suggested python code i am very new to python.